# SoundCloud iOS SDK fails to find all header files. libSoundCloudUI/CocoaSoundCloudUI

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I have spent hours over the past week trying to figure out why SoundCloud suddenly stopped working in an app I'm working on. Figuring it might have been file-location related, I completely removed it and re-added the submodules. Then re-added after that didn't work. Then re-added. Then searched. Then nothing.

I've tried re-adding the SoundCloud submodules, and have followed the directions on the SoundCloud site to the T, and still, I get compiler error after error, warning after warning. I add the linker flags as stated, and include the needed frameworks and dependencies. I have absolutely no idea why I'm getting missing file errors.

Changing the Header Search Path (in either MY project file or libSoundCloudUI) just shifts what file can't be found, and when I somehow manage to get SoundCloud to compile with my program, anytime I commit my changes to my Git repository, the submodules are lost and the next person to open the project doesn't have the code, thus making me start over. Pointing the header search path directly to the source code doesn't work, even when it's recursive.

What could be happening? No matter what I do, specifically CocoaSoundCloudUI

Some of the errors I've been getting:

```
Use of undeclared identifier: 'kTermsofService' (This has a few other keys that aren't being found)
Header file not found: <insert random file include in headers and in source folder>
```

If my app didn't need SoundCloud support I would have dropped it already. This has been such a nightmare - any help would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: I've also tried deleting my .gitmodules and modules folder within my git folder - no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Sean Michael Dorian,

indeed, we have updated `CocoaSoundCloudAPI` and `CocoaSoundCloudUI` lately and according to your error message you have not updated **both** repos, i.e. you need to run

`git submodule update --init --recursive`.

If you have issues w/ submodules in general I recommend you switching to [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) it turns the management of your library dependencies into a no-brainer.

We also provide a [Demo Xcode project](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudDemo/tree/feature/demo-proj-with-cocoapods) to check out such a setup.

This should help you resolving the issues let me know if you are missing anything there.

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried what you said and it didn't change anything. Re adding the submodule and trying what you suggested didn't change the problem either. It says it can't find 'kSCBorderRadius' in SCTextField.

Comment: hm, can you please `cd` into the `CocoaSoundCloudAPI` folder and run `git show HEAD`? It should point to `5f76027` if not you need to `git pull origin master`

Comment: The same needs to be done for `CocoaSoundCloudUI` there the HEAD should point to `0f2d0c9` and the `SoundCloud.bundle` should contain couple more assets

Comment: One of the repositories was behind, but I'm still getting the error:

`/Users/NAME/Desktop/DIR/CocoaSoundCloudUI/Sources/SoundCloudUI/SCLoginView.m:233:55: Use of undeclared identifier 'kTermsOfServiceURL'`

Comment: This identifier `kTermsOfServiceURL` should be included in the updated `SCConstants.h` within `CocoaSoundCloudAPI`. Have you added `-all_load -ObjC` in your Build Settings under "Other Linker Flags" and also tried cleaning the product before building it again?

Comment: If it still does not work can you provide me a link to your github repo then I could take a look at it?

Comment: I've added the linker flags according to the instructions. Unfortunately, I can't give you access to the repo due to an NDA.

Comment: It's only the CocoaSoundCloudUI project that's throwing errors.

Comment: Alright, unfortunately then it is hard to determine what's wrong. Here are the steps I followed, which works flawlessly:

1. `git clone https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudDemo.git`
2. `git submodule update --init --recursive`
3. Open the `CocoaSoundCloudDemo.xcworkspace`
4. Here is a screenshot of my Build Settings https://www.evernote.com/shard/s272/sh/c14ece86-2200-405e-889f-574ded45a826/e31a1aeacd633a3fe215218d5a99e86d/deep/0/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-24%20at%2011.42.55%20AM.jpg

Comment: otherwise you should really check-out CocoaPods the links I have sent you in my first answer above

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob, much appreciated! I'll update this once I have it resolved.